correct usage/type with conjunctive adverb
a) Our vacation was wonderful, however, it was too short.
Is a) incorrect or acceptable use? I understand it should have a semicolon with a comma or start a new sentence, but some resources conflict with this.
I have included some examples below.
b) Some people disagree with this theory, however, it's never been proven right.
c) He is rich, however he's not happy.
Also, with this example (c), it just takes a comma.
https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/587367976388672359/
https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/398146423311058359/

I think that 'however' should precede a more lengthy alternative. "Our vacation was wonderful, but too short."

Does this answer your question? Use of a semicolon before, and comma after, 'however'

Adverbs are not conjunctions and cannot connect clauses as such. “However” may be similar to “but” semantically, but that doesn’t mean they are interchangeable syntactically.
